# A problem on sum of sinusoids of different amplitudes and phases but with same frequency.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $N$ points $\{x_i\} \in (0,1)$ and $N$ real numbers $\{d_i\}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}d_i = 0$. Can we find a function of the form $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{M}A_k\sin(2\pi x + \theta_i)$$ such that $f(x_i) = d_i, i = 1,2,3,...N$, $M$ can be chosen sufficiently large. Is it possible always?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rarely.  That sum can be written as a single $A\sin 2\pi x+\theta$.

Expand each one into $p_i\sin 2\pi x+q_i\cos 2\pi x$.
Let $p=\sum p_i$ and $q=\sum q_i$.
Combine them back into a single sine.